# vba code for goto specific column on an acive row

Tags: vba

I have an excel which is spread quite long with multiple columns.
I would like to create a vba with dropdown having column headers as a selection.
on selecting it should take me to the selected column of the active row.

Comment: what's the question? You want someone to write the code for you? Can you at least show us that you did something?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a data validation list in Cell A1 with a list of the column names then this code will activate the correct column header. I've taken that your column headers are in Range A1 to Z1. Change this range to whatever your column range is.

This code goes in the sheet module of whatever sheet you are using.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Cells.Count = 1 And target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Set Rng = Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:=Range("a1").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Rng.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```